# Dynamic getting boxed into object type on deserialization

Tags: c#, dynamic, json.net

In one unit of my application:

```
// response is a string. After this line executes, obj is dynamic as expected
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
if (obj.Foo == "this works fine because obj is dynamic") {
   // Do whatever
}
```

In another unit in my application:

```
// Again, response is a string. This time, obj ends up being an object, NOT dynamic
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
obj.Foo; // Fails because obj is an object
((dynamic)obj).Foo; // Works once I have type casted

// Every single method here returns an object and not dynamic as expected
dynamic obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
var obj3 = (dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
dynamic obj4 = (dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
dynamic obj5;
obj5 = (dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
```

I don't mind typecasting this. But I don't think I should have to. And typecasting this feels like a hack. I'd rather understand why this behaves differently in some cases.

Screenshots in case it is something dumb that I am not seeing:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you might want to investigate how the two "units" differ.

Comment: I copy/pasted the usings from the top to synchronize them. I can't think of what else would be different.

Comment: What’s a “unit”? Are they in the same project?

Comment: Different *.cs file. Yes same project.

Comment: Is it the current version of `Newtonsoft.Json` library (11.0.2)?